# custom Python get BDay range

Tags: python, datetime

I defined a function to create Business date range with custom holiday calendar. I think I got myself into an infinite loop but don't know why?

```
import datetime as dt

def get_bdate(start, end, hoildays):
list = []
while  start < end:
    if start.weekday() >= 5: # sunday = 6; skipping weekends
        continue
    if start in holidays: # holidays is a custom set of dates
        continue
    list.append(start)
    start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
return list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not incrementing start in your loop if it's a weekday or if it's a holiday. By just using `continue` you end up using the same start value indefinitely!

```
import datetime as dt

def get_bdate(start, end, hoildays):
    my_list = []
    while  start < end:
        if start.weekday() > 5 or start not in holidays: 
            my_list.append(start)
        start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return my_list
```

To use your earlier example more exactly (although it repeats the `start +=` line:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_bdate(start, end, hoildays):
    my_list = []
    while  start < end:
        if start.weekday() >= 5: # sunday = 6; skipping weekends
            start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
            continue
        if start in holidays: # holidays is a custom set of dates
            start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
            continue
        my_list.append(start)
        start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return my_list
```

Comment: Oh Gee. Just noticed that epic fail!

Comment: @ChristopherApple: Using `list` as a variable name clobbers the [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: @DavidCullen Sure enough! Fixed in my latest edit. I was just mirroring what his original example was, and forgot to check for that sort of thing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop:

You need to change your code so that `start` is always incremented:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_bdate(start, end, holidays):
    result = list()
    while start < end:
        if start.weekday() >= 5: # sunday = 6; skipping weekends
            pass
        elif start in holidays: # holidays is a custom set of dates
            pass
        else:
            result.append(start)
        start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return result
```

Also, do not use `list` as a variable name as you will clobber the [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: Thanks for the help! this is useful!